# error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment c++

Tags: c++

```
template <typename Type>
bool Lazy_deletion_node<Type>::insert( Type const &obj ) {
    if(this == nullptr){
        Lazy_deletion_node<Type> *tmp = new Lazy_deletion_node( obj );
        this = tmp;
        return true;
    }
    else if(obj == this->retrieve()){
        if(erased){
            erased = false;
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if(obj < this->retrieve()){
        left()->insert( obj );
    } 
    else if(obj > this->retrieve()){
        right()->insert( obj );
    }
}
```

Hey guys, I'm trying to to do an insert for a Lazy deletion tree, which is basically a binary search tree except that I mark the nodes as "erased" instead of actually removing them from the tree. This is a method to insert a new node into the tree containing the object obj. nullptr is defined to be 0.

I first test to see if the pointer is pointing to 0. If it is, I create a node that stores obj inside and then I try to make the pointer point to this newly created node.

However, when I try to compile, it gives me the error that lvalue is required as left operand of assignment on the line that reads this = tmp;. Can anybody tell me why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A better question: when could `this == nullptr`?

Comment: I was thinking that this == nullptr when an empty tree tries to call the insert method.

Comment: We'd need to see all of your code to tell you what's going on, but `this` can't ever be null.  If it was, you'd be invoking a function on an object that's a null object.

Answer (score 3):

You can't reassign `this`. Like the error says, it's not a modifiable l-value.

However, if `this` was a pointing at an object that had a mutable field of the same type you're trying to assign, you could access it through `this->myField` or `this.myField`, depending on whether it's a pointer or a reference.

Comment: Is there a way for me to make the pointer that is calling this method to point at the new node?

Comment: Yeah, but like i said, you need to have your node as a field on your calling object, or passed as a parameter to the function

Comment: I see, so I should actually be checking if this->element == nullptr;

however, i get a segmentation fault whenever i invoke the insert method now.

Answer (score 1):

"this" is a reserved keyword that is a pointer to the object currently in scope (loosely similar to "self" if you're familiar with Python). It is designed to ALWAYS point to the object currently in scope, which means you cannot change its value.

What you're trying to do when you use "this = tmp;" is a little bit like trying to use "false = 10;"

Comment: I've changed my code so that it's:

    if(element == nullptr){
  element = obj;
  return true;
 }

but now I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: It'd be helpful to see that in context. Feel free to update your original question so others can see this change too.

I'm not sure, but it looks like "obj" is not a pointer, in which case you may very well be able to assign it to "element," but if "element" is a pointer, then it now points to whatever address is numerically equivalent to the value of "obj." In short, the value of "element" should be the address of an object, not the object's value.

Comment: (ran out of time on my edit) ...If that memory address belongs to someone else, then you will get a segmentation fault when you try to access it.

"obj" has a value and it resides at an address. "element = &obj" will get you the ADDRESS of obj.